# Traefik create frontend rule in consul for docker backend

Tags: consul, traefik

I actually use traefik with docker and everything works fine. 
But now, i would like to create new frontend rule with my apps using consul as a KV store.

So i created some key:

```
/traefik/frontends/frontend1/backend    backend2
/traefik/frontends/frontend1/routes/test_1/rule Host:test.localhost
```

And hope to see them in my traefik UI but nothing appeared.

Looking in logs, i can see

```
time="2018-04-26T19:31:06Z" level=debug msg="Configuration received from provider consul: {}"
time="2018-04-26T19:31:06Z" level=info msg="Skipping same configuration for provider consul"
```

Connection with consul is okay and i saw some logs Cannot get key... so i created them to see if this was causing a bug

Have you an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a backend?  In my testing, the bare minimum to get it to appear in the UI is the following:

```
traefik/frontends/frontend-test/backend backend-test
traefik/backends/backend-test
```

This is not enough however to have a working frontend/backend, but should get something in the UI.